# Visual studio 2008 WPF designer questions

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have 2 question about xaml editor.

1. I need to show xaml editor keyboard shortcut like F7 and Shift+F7
2. How to make default view as xaml editor? When i choosing 'view designer' button from solution explorer, xaml editor and designer window shown. How to set default editor to xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 2:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous -> Always open documents in full XAML view